# Conservation of angular momentum in a rod with hinge on one end

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, angular-momentum, free-body-diagram

Consider the case a rod with hinge on one end in horizontal position. At the instant when it is released, the weight of the rod is going to give it a torque with an acceleration. Why is angular momentum not conserved here? Since weight of the rod is part of the system, what is the external force here?

Comment: The pivot${}{}$

Comment: You said it yourself. Gravity exerts a torque. Torques change angular momentum. So angular momentum isn't conserved. It's like if you were to drop a ball. If you just consider the momentum of the ball, it is not conserved because gravity is a net force acting on it. Forces change momentum. So the ball's momentum is not conserved.

Comment: Well,I thought it was an internal force.It comes out to be an internal force only when I consider the Earth and rod as a system.But I got another doubt.After releasing the rod from initial horizontal position, gravity still acts on it which means there exists an external force.Should this give rise to a torque?Because I encountered a problem where torque at this instant is said to be zero.

Comment: A split second after the rod is released, does it have an angular acceleration?   Consider that question, and what it implies about torque on the rod.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong comment.What I meant was when the rod is in vertical position,does gravity still give rise to a torque?

Comment: It then rotates due to inertia (if angular speed is enough)  , otherwise stops and reverses rotation...